# Is there a Python library for drawing SVG and saving them as other formats?

Tags: python, svg, jpeg

As the title implies, I wrote a script because I needed to generate large numbers of images with random circles lines etc in them, for this I have used the [svgwrite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgwrite/) library to create the DOM objects.

But for the next stage I need them in either the .png or .jpeg format, I'm pretty sure I could write a script to convert the previously generated SVG if they were saved on the hard disk.

I would like it to be all in one script and not to create temporary svg files, so does somebody know of a Python library in which I can generate svg objects and then save them to .png or jpeg ?

To be more to the point I need to generate some images circles etc, in a easy way as with with SVG, which then I can use with the PIL image processing library.

Comment: If you're worried about temporary files just because you want the speed of RAM, consider a file-based solution and set up a RAM disk as temp storage.